# How can I use Mehrotra's predictor-corrector primal-dual interior point method to solve a problem that is not in the form of cTx?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am not very familiar with optimization methods. I am studying the paper "Blind channel identification for speech dereverberation using l1-norm sparse learning" (here: http://linyq.com/NIPS2007.pdf).

The problem in eq. (4) is formulated as:
$$
\text{argmin} \| \boldsymbol{\mathrm{X}}_2 \boldsymbol{\mathrm{h}}_1 - \boldsymbol{\mathrm{X}}_1 \boldsymbol{\mathrm{h}}_2 \|^{2} + \lambda \sum_{j = 0}^{L - 1} \left[ |h_1(j)| + |h_2(j)|\right]
$$
subject to $h_1(l) = 1$. The author states he uses Mehrotra's predictor-corrector primal-dual interior point method to solve this problem.

However, the method he mentions solves problems of the form $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{c}}^{T}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}$ subject to $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{A}}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}} = \boldsymbol{\mathrm{b}}$. With my limited experience and understanding of such methods I cannot readily see how I can user Mehrotra's method to solve the problem in the paper.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: The norm is the Euclidean norm. The optimization variables are $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{h}}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{h}}_2$. These are column vectors. $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{X}}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{X}}_2$ are matrices.

Comment: Primal-dual interior point methods are more general than that. They can solve LPs, SOCPs and SDPs, for example.  What are the variables in your optimization problem?  Which norm is being used in the first term?

Comment: The paper actually uses the squared norm, presumably the Euclidean norm. Hence they probably cast it as a QP. Frankly, it is a poor choice for sparse recovery models like this; too expensive. Proximal gradient and other first-order methods are more commonly used now (Unless you are Jacek Gondzio. ;-)) Stephen Wright himself---whose book was cited as a source for the interior-point method---has developed SparSA for similar problems.